# SELECT DISTINCT on one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server, I have...

```
ID  SKU     PRODUCT
=======================
1   FOO-23  Orange
2   BAR-23  Orange
3   FOO-24  Apple
4   FOO-25  Orange
```

I want

```
1   FOO-23  Orange
3   FOO-24  Apple
```

This query isn't getting me there. How can I SELECT DISTINCT on just one column?

```
SELECT 
[ID],[SKU],[PRODUCT]
FROM [TestData] 
WHERE ([PRODUCT] = 
(SELECT DISTINCT [PRODUCT] FROM [TestData] WHERE ([SKU] LIKE 'FOO-%')) 
ORDER BY [ID]
```

Comment: Can we assume that you don't care about the suffix on the SKU column data? I.E., You only care about "FOO-" and not "FOO-xx"

Comment: What is your logic for choosing ID = 1, SKU = FOO-23 over the other values? It's easy to create a query that answers specfically for ID = 1 but fails for a general case

Comment: gbn - this is an overly simplified example (obviously). What I am trying to show is one example that satisfies both criteria. There isn't (and need not be) logic to which one is chosen.

Answer (score 390, accepted):

Assuming that you're on SQL Server 2005 or greater, you can use a CTE with ROW_NUMBER():

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT ID, SKU, Product,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber
         FROM   MyTable
         WHERE  SKU LIKE 'FOO%') AS a
WHERE   a.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: You aren't using a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) in your query. That's just a derived table. But you are right that you *could* have used a CTE here.

Comment: leave out "AS" for oracle -> ...WHERE  SKU LIKE 'FOO%') a WHERE   a.RowNumber = 1

Comment: This works although it's not a CTE ( ;WITH CTE ...... ) . more of a sub query with partition by inside....

Answer (score 60):

The simplest solution would be to use a subquery for finding the minimum ID matching your query. In the subquery you use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT * FROM [TestData] WHERE [ID] IN (
   SELECT MIN([ID]) FROM [TestData]
   WHERE [SKU] LIKE 'FOO-%'
   GROUP BY [PRODUCT]
)
```

Comment: GROUPBY is not useful when you have several columns, because you need to bring all your columns in the GROUP BY statement.

Answer (score 15):

try this:

```
SELECT 
    t.*
    FROM TestData t
        INNER JOIN (SELECT
                        MIN(ID) as MinID
                        FROM TestData
                        WHERE SKU LIKE 'FOO-%'
                   ) dt ON t.ID=dt.MinID
```

**EDIT**
once the OP corrected his samle output (previously had only ONE result row, now has all shown), this is the correct query:

```
declare @TestData table (ID int, sku char(6), product varchar(15))
insert into @TestData values (1 ,  'FOO-23'      ,'Orange')
insert into @TestData values (2 ,  'BAR-23'      ,'Orange')
insert into @TestData values (3 ,  'FOO-24'      ,'Apple')
insert into @TestData values (4 ,  'FOO-25'      ,'Orange')

--basically the same as @Aaron Alton's answer:
SELECT
    dt.ID, dt.SKU, dt.Product
    FROM (SELECT
              ID, SKU, Product, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT ORDER BY ID) AS RowID
              FROM @TestData
              WHERE  SKU LIKE 'FOO-%'
         ) AS dt
    WHERE dt.RowID=1
    ORDER BY dt.ID
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is a version, basically the same as a couple of the other answers, but that you can copy paste into your SQL server Management Studio to test, (and without generating any unwanted tables), thanks to some inline values.

```
WITH [TestData]([ID],[SKU],[PRODUCT]) AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES
        (1,   'FOO-23',  'Orange'),
        (2,   'BAR-23',  'Orange'),
        (3,   'FOO-24',  'Apple'),
        (4,   'FOO-25',  'Orange')
    )
    AS [TestData]([ID],[SKU],[PRODUCT])
)

SELECT * FROM [TestData] WHERE [ID] IN 
(
    SELECT MIN([ID]) 
    FROM [TestData] 
    GROUP BY [PRODUCT]
)
```

Result

```
ID  SKU     PRODUCT
1   FOO-23  Orange
3   FOO-24  Apple
```

I have ignored the following ...

```
WHERE ([SKU] LIKE 'FOO-%')
```

as its only part of the authors faulty code and not part of the question. It's unlikely to be helpful to people looking here.

Comment: A great idea for dev work and testing without having to create test tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I know it was asked over 6 years ago, but knowledge is still knowledge.
This is different solution than all above, as I had to run it under SQL Server 2000:

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE([ID] int, [SKU] char(6), [Product] varchar(15))
INSERT INTO @TestData values (1 ,'FOO-23', 'Orange')
INSERT INTO @TestData values (2 ,'BAR-23', 'Orange')
INSERT INTO @TestData values (3 ,'FOO-24', 'Apple')
INSERT INTO @TestData values (4 ,'FOO-25', 'Orange')

SELECT DISTINCT  [ID] = ( SELECT TOP 1 [ID]  FROM @TestData Y WHERE Y.[Product] = X.[Product])
                ,[SKU]= ( SELECT TOP 1 [SKU] FROM @TestData Y WHERE Y.[Product] = X.[Product])
                ,[PRODUCT] 
            FROM @TestData X
```

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT min (id) AS 'ID', min(sku) AS 'SKU', Product
    FROM TestData
    WHERE sku LIKE 'FOO%' -- If you want only the sku that matchs with FOO%
    GROUP BY product 
    ORDER BY 'ID'
```

Comment: Was going to +1 this, because I think GROUP BY is the right way to go - but the minimum ID and the minimum SKU may not happen to belong to the same record.  It's hard to determine what are the correct ID and SKU to report for a given PRODUCT.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

`SELECT * FROM [TestData] WHERE Id IN(SELECT DISTINCT MIN(Id) FROM [TestData] GROUP BY Product)`