# How to remove duplicates from table using SQL query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table which is as follows:

```
emp_name   emp_address  sex  matial_status  
uuuu       eee          m    s
iiii       iii          f    s
uuuu       eee          m    s
```

I want to remove the duplicate entries based on 3 fields emp_name, emp_address and sex.
and my resultant table (after removing the duplicates) should look like -

```
emp_name    emp_address   sex   marital_status
uuuu        eee           m     s
iiii        iii           f     s
```

I am not able to recall how to write a SQL Query for this. an anyone pls help?

Comment: If you're not going to base duplication on all the columns of the row, then when a duplicate is found, how will you decide which row to keep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all four column values are duplicated so you can do this -

```
select distinct emp_name, emp_address, sex, marital_status
from YourTable
```

However if marital status can be different and you have some other column based on which to choose (for eg you want latest record based on a column create_date) you can do this

```
select emp_name, emp_address, sex, marital_status
from YourTable a
where not exists (select 1 
                   from YourTable b
                  where b.emp_name = a.emp_name and
                        b.emp_address = a.emp_address and
                        b.sex = a.sex and
                        b.create_date >= a.create_date)
```

Comment: This doesnt answer his question imo. He wants a UPDATE or DELETE FROM statement, not a single SELECT statement that is not permanent and does not alter the table in any way.

Answer (score 5):

I would create a new table with a unique index over the columns that you want to keep unique. Then do an insert from the old table into the new, ignoring the warnings about duplicated rows. Lastly, I would drop (or rename) the old table and replace it with the new table. In MySQL, this would look like

```
CREATE TABLE tmp LIKE mytable;
ALTER TABLE tmp ADD UNIQUE INDEX myindex (emp_name, emp_address, sex, marital_status);
INSERT IGNORE INTO tmp SELECT * FROM mytable;
DROP TABLE mytable;
RENAME TABLE tmp TO mytable;
```

Or something similar (this is totally untested).

Answer (score 4):

This is not a query but a delete statement. It will delete/remove duplicate rows from your table

```
;with C as
(
  select row_number() over(partition by DUPLICATE_VAARS_DECISION 
                           order by NODE_EQ_NO) as rn
  from yourtable
)
delete C
where rn > 1
```

If you are only interested in querying the table and get the non duplicates as a result you should use this instead.

```
;with C as
(
  select *,
         row_number() over(partition by DUPLICATE_VAARS_DECISION 
                           order by NODE_EQ_NO) as rn
  from yourtable
)
select *
from C
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks this works! For the first statement to delete duplicates, it's more understandable like this:                              ;with C as
(
  select row_number() over(partition by Description 
                           order by Description) as rn
  from [YourTable]
)
delete C
where rn > 1

Answer (score 2):

one way

```
select emp_name,   emp_address,  sex,  max(marital_status) as marital_status
from Yourtable
group by emp_name,   emp_address,  sex
```

Since I don't know what you want, I used max for the marital status

See also [Including an Aggregated Column's Related Values](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/including-an-aggregated-column-s-related) for more examples

Comment: why you have used max function??

Comment: See @Ralph's comment on your question.  What is your logic for determining which duplicate marital_status to keep?

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with trading space for performance and simplicity then the duplicates in `emp_name | emp_address | sex` combo can be eliminated, by the introduction of a calculated/derived column using `CHECKSUM()` TSQL method and `DISTINCT` keyword while querying.

Heres an example of CHECKSUM :

```
SELECT CHECKSUM(*) FROM HumanResources.Employee WHERE EmployeeID = 2
```

Google around and create a dependent column that contains the checksum of the 3 columns.
Then you can select distinct rows by looking [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966176/tsql-select-distinct-on-one-column)

Comment: I also invite some critiques on this answer - I need to know if this is good enough (even for a table with 800k rows)

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is here:
Use this SQL statement to identify the extra duplicated rows:

```
 select * from Employee a 

    where %%physloc%% > 

        (select min(%%physloc%%) from Employee b 

            where a.emp_name=b.emp_name and a.emp_address=b.emp_address and a.sex=b.sex);
```

you will get the extra row:

```
uuuu   eee m   s
```

Use this SQL statement to delete the extra duplicated rows:

```
 delete from Employee a 

    where %%physloc%% > 

        (select min(%%physloc%%) from Employee b 

            where a.emp_name=b.emp_name and a.emp_address=b.emp_address and a.sex=b.sex);
```

For all duplicated records, only the one with lowest physical location is kept. This method can be applied to remove all kinds of duplicated rows.

I am assuming that you use MS SQL Server. If you are using Oracle DB, then you can just replace '**%%physloc%%**' with '**rowid**'

Enjoy the code!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post, but recently I tested a solution and want to share if any one can find my solution helpful -

> CREATE TABLE `tmpTable` LIKE `yourTable`;
>   insert into `tmpTable` (`col1`, `col2` ... `colN`) SELECT distinct `col1`, `col2` ... `colN` FROM `yourTable` WHERE 1;
>   drop table `yourTable`;
>   RENAME TABLE `tmpTable` TO `yourTable`;

Please note, insert into statement may execute without primary key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't satisfied with distinct try below

```
SELECT MAX(ID) AS MaxRecordID, max(FirstName) AS fname
    FROM [SampleDB].[dbo].[Employee]
    GROUP BY [FirstName], 
             [LastName], 
             [Country]
```

Use the Max key word with groupBy. You can use max for any type column. Integer, Varchar and etc.