# mysql, how to delete duplicate data?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table with some duplicate values and i want to remove them:

table1:

```
id   |   access       |   num
12       1144712030       101
13       1144712030       101
14       1154512035       102
15       1154512035       102
```

i would like to remove the duplicates so i will have left:

```
id   |   access       |   num
12       1144712030       101
14       1154512035       102
```

any idea how to do this in a mysql command?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicates from table using SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676110/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-table-using-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpler solution i think would be:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table as SELECT id,DISTINCT access,num FROM original_table
TRUNCATE TABLE original_table
INSERT INTO original_table SELECT * FROM new_table
DROP TABLE new_table;
```

Note:

I think some kind of cursor could be used, and maybe a temporary table. But you should be really careful.

Comment: Yes, i messed it up with new/old. I Changed the names now.

Answer (score 1):

if your table called foo, rename in foo_old, re-create table foo as a structure identical to foo_old.
Make a query with the DISTINCT operator obtained and the results reported on Table foo_old enter them in foo.

Answer (score 0):

do a quick search here for DELETE DUPLICATE ROWS

you'll find a ton of examples.