# Removing duplicates from a table

Tags: sql, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove duplicates from table using SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676110/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-table-using-sql-query)

I am not able to resolve this issue.

I have a table which is as follows:

```
SYS_ID  SUB_NET_ID  NODE_NAME   NODE_ID NODE_EQ_NO  NODE_VAR_NO TEMP_ID EQUIP_TYPE  EQ_ID   VAR_ID  VAR_OBJECT  VAR_NAME    VAR_SUBSET  VAR_SET CALC_VAR_TYPE   DATA_TYPE   DOF COEFF_OBJECT    COEFF_NODE_ID   COEFF_VAR_ID    COEFF_VAR_SET   COEFF_VAR_TYPE  COEFF_VAR_SUBSET    COEFF_VAR_NAME  OPERAND SIGN    RETAIN  VAR_TP_OFFSET   COEFF_TP_OFFSET COEFF_VAR_SUBTYE    VALUE   RHS_DECISION    DUPLICATE_VARS_DECISION
15  1   TTOL_BLEND  16  3   6   14      9   0   SIMPAR  ZERO    UNDEF   PARSPEC VAR CONTINOUS                       0   0       0               0   0   0   0       0   ZEROPARSPECUNDEF    166
15  1   TTOL_BLEND  16  4   6   14      10  0   SIMPAR  ZERO    UNDEF   PARSPEC VAR CONTINOUS                       0   0       0               0   0   0   0       0   ZEROPARSPECUNDEF    166
15  1   TTOL_BLEND  16  5   6   14      10  0   SIMPAR  ZERO    UNDEF   PARSPEC VAR CONTINOUS                       0   0       0               0   0   0   0       0   ZEROPARSPECUNDEF    166
```

I want to remove the duplicate entries based on DUPLICATE_VARS_DECISION.
and my resultant table (after removing the duplicates) should look like -

```
SYS_ID  SUB_NET_ID  NODE_NAME   NODE_ID NODE_EQ_NO  NODE_VAR_NO TEMP_ID EQUIP_TYPE  EQ_ID   VAR_ID  VAR_OBJECT  VAR_NAME    VAR_SUBSET  VAR_SET CALC_VAR_TYPE   DATA_TYPE   DOF COEFF_OBJECT    COEFF_NODE_ID   COEFF_VAR_ID    COEFF_VAR_SET   COEFF_VAR_TYPE  COEFF_VAR_SUBSET    COEFF_VAR_NAME  OPERAND SIGN    RETAIN  VAR_TP_OFFSET   COEFF_TP_OFFSET COEFF_VAR_SUBTYE    VALUE   RHS_DECISION    DUPLICATE_VARS_DECISION
15  1   TTOL_BLEND  16  3   6   14      9   0   SIMPAR  ZERO    UNDEF   PARSPEC VAR CONTINOUS                       0   0       0               0   0   0   0       0   ZEROPARSPECUNDEF    166
```

I am not able to recall how to write a SQL Query for this. an anyone pls help?

Comment: How do you know which of the duplicates to keep?