# Sybase SQL Select Distinct Based on Multiple Columns with an ID

Tags: sql, sybase, distinct

I'm trying to query a sybase server to get examples of different types of data we hold for testing purposes.

I have a table that looks like the below (abstracted)

```
Animals table:
id | type | breed           | name
------------------------------------
1  | dog  | german shepard  | Bernie
2  | dog  | german shepard  | James
3  | dog  | husky           | Laura
4  | cat  | british blue    | Mr Fluffles
5  | cat  | other           | Laserchild
6  | cat  | british blue    | Sleepy head
7  | fish | goldfish        | Goldie
```

As I mentioned I want an example of each type so for the above table would like a results set like (in reality I just want the ID's):

```
id | type | breed           
---------------------------
1  | dog  | german shepard  
3  | dog  | husky          
4  | cat  | british blue   
5  | cat  | other          
7  | fish | goldfish
```

I've tried multiple combinations of queries such as the below but they are either invalid SQL (for sybase) or return invalid results

```
  SELECT id, DISTINCT ON type, breed FROM animals
  SELECT id, DISTINCT(type, breed) FROM animals
  SELECT id FROM animals GROUP BY type, breed
```

I've found other questions such as [SELECT DISTINCT on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966176/select-distinct-on-one-column) but this only deal with one column

Do you have any idea how to implement this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have to use aggregate function `max` or `min` for column ID. It will return only one ID for grouped columns.

```
select max(Id), type, breed 
from animals
group by type, breed
```

EDIT:

Other different ways to do it:

**With having and aggregate function**

```
select id, type, breed  
from animals 
group by type, breed  
having id = max(Id)
```

**With having and aggregate subquery**

```
select id, type, breed 
from animals a1
group by type, breed 
having id = (
               select max(id)
               from animals a2
               where a2.type = a1.type
               and   a2.breed = a1.breed
            )
```

Comment: This worked as expected but took around 20 mins to run, will leave the question open searching for a more elegant (and speedy) solution but will accept if noone has any other suggestions!

Comment: I found other ways to do it. I'm not sure if it will work faster, maybe second proposition. Maybe first suggestion is more readable. I edited the post.

Answer (score -1):

Try this and let me know if it works:

```
select distinct breed, max(id) as id , max(type) as type
from animals
```

You may have to play around with `max()`
The arbitrary choice here is max(), but you could arbitrarily use min() instead.
[`max()`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp) returns the largest value for that columns, [`min()`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_min.asp) the smallest