# Applying distinct in multiple columns in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I am trying to get distinct result by only one column( message).  I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  [id], [message]
  FROM Example table
GROUP BY [message]
```

But it doesn't show desired result.
Please let me know how can I do it?

Example table:

```
  id | Message     | 
    --  ------------
     1 | mike       | 
     2 | mike       |
     3 | star       | 
     4 | star       |  
     5 | star       | 
     6 | sky        |
     7 | sky        | 
     8 | sky        |
```

Result table:

```
id | Message     | 
--  ------------
 1 | mike       | 
 3 | star      |
 6 | sky       |
```

Comment: use `max` or `min` on the id column.

Comment: Please google and learn about the GROUP BY clause in SQL.  Also google the error message you got when you ran the query you posted.

Comment: _"it doesn't show desired result"_ No, because you got an error instead which is quite meaningful. You cannot use `Group By` on one column but select two columns. Consider that every `Message`-group can contain multiple `Id`'s, but you only want to see one. Sql-Server now wants to know which. Therefore either use `Min`,`Max` or other aggregate functions on the column(s) which are not part of the `Group By`.

Comment: So *what* value do you want for the other column? You need to make a choice and then inform us (and, ultimately, SQL Server) what rules you want to use to select one of possibly many *different* values for the other column(s).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT DISTINCT on one column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966176/select-distinct-on-one-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the column you want to be unique and use an aggregate function on the other column. You want the lowest `id` for every message, so use `MIN()`

```
select min(id) as id,
       message
from your_table
group by message
```

Comment: Uncredited duplicate of the logic in this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9903573/1507566