# Distinct on one column, order by computed column

Tags: sql-server

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966176/select-distinct-on-one-column) and [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24327/how-to-select-distinct-for-one-column-and-any-in-another-column), but mine is a little different and I can't get it to work.

I'm using SQL Server 2016. My existing query is below, and it works fine. It selects the `Interest` row and orders them by the number of `Post`s that interest has.

```
-- this is in a stored procedure, variables are valid

select i.[Id], i.[Name], i.[Description],
(
    select count(*) from [Post] p where p.[InterestId] = i.[Id] and p.[CreatedAt] >= @AfterTime
) as PostCount
from Interest i
order by PostCount desc
offset (@Start - 1) rows fetch next (@ReturnNum) rows only
```

I now want to change this. There's another column in the Interest table with `InterestCategoryId`; that's a foreign key for a 1:M relationship with `InterestCategory`. I want to get the same info as before, but limited to only a single `InterestCategoryId`--I'd only get one result per category. How can I accomplish this? I'm trying this code, but it throws an error that `PostCount` isn't a valid column.

```
select [Id], [Name], [Description], PostCount
from
(
    select [Id], [Name], [Description],
    (
        select count(*) from [Post] po where po.[InterestId] = [Id] and po.[CreatedAt] >= @AfterTime
    ) as PostCount,
    row_number() over(partition by [InterestCategoryId] order by PostCount desc) rn
    from [Interest]
) i
where rn = 1
order by PostCount desc
offset (@Start - 1) rows fetch next (@ReturnNum) rows only
```

Example interest data is below. If we assume that interest ID 1 has more posts than 2, I would want interests 1, 3, and 4 returned.

```
ID | Name | Description | InterestCategoryId
---|------|-------------|-------------------
 1 | Test | Test int    | 1
 2 | Tes2 | Test int2   | 1
 3 | Tes3 | Test int3   | 2
 4 | Tes4 | Test int4   | 3
```

Comment: A simple `min` aggregation function will do it. I think. Try this: `select min(id) id, min(Name) name, min(Description) Description, min(InterestCategoryId) from Interest ` Since you said that only wants rows 1, 3 and 4 returned that will do it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos It could be 2, 3, and 4 though if interest 2 has more posts than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't pretty, but it runs. I am hoping it helps you get to where you want to go.

```
select [Id], [Name], [Description], PostCount
from
(
    select [Id], [Name], [Description],
    (
        select count(*) 
        from [Post] po 
        where po.[InterestId] = [Id] 
        and po.[CreatedAt] >= @AfterTime
    ) as PostCount,
    row_number() over(partition by [InterestCategoryId] order by (
        select count(*) 
        from [Post] po 
        where po.[InterestId] = [Id] 
        and po.[CreatedAt] >= @AfterTime
    ) desc) rn
    from [Interest]
) i
where rn = 1
order by PostCount desc
offset (@Start - 1) rows fetch next (@ReturnNum) rows only
```

If you want to avoid repeating that `COUNT` sub-query, try it this way.

```
select [Id], [Name], [Description], PostCount
from
(    
    select AA.Id, AA.Name, AA.Description, AA.PostCount, AA.[InterestCategoryId],
    row_number() over(partition by [InterestCategoryId] order by PostCount desc) rn
    from    (select [Id], [Name], [Description], [InterestCategoryId],
    (
        select count(*) 
        from [Post] po 
        where po.[InterestId] = [Id] 
        and po.[CreatedAt] >= @AfterTime
    ) as PostCount
    from [Interest]) AA
) i
where rn = 1
order by PostCount desc
offset (@Start - 1) rows fetch next (@ReturnNum) rows only
```

Thanks for the reminder of the `OFFSET` clause. I don't get an opportunity to use that very often.

Hope this helps. Good luck!