# SQL Filter Issues

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sorry for not being more clear in the title but I didn't know what to put there, if anyone has a suggestion based on my question, please let me know so I can change it. I have also included an SQL Fiddle below, it might be helpful to understand my explanation.

I'm currently creating a query that is supposed to return information about some report documents. These documents have a status which is saved in another table. Every time a document's status is updated a new record will be created in the Report_Status table. My goal is to show all these report documents with the **current** status together with some relevant information. This information is included in my fiddle but the problem lies mainly with the Report_Status table.

The solution I have right now gives the following output:

```
|        Study |           Site | Visit |         Report |              Status |
|--------------|----------------|-------|----------------|---------------------|
| Tester (UAT) | Mercy Hospital |   SQV | SQV Report_GSG | Authoring (Default) |
| Tester (UAT) | Mercy Hospital |   SQV | SQV Report_GSG | Authoring (Default) |
| Tester (UAT) | Mercy Hospital |   SQV | SQV Report_GSG | Authoring (Default) |
| Tester (UAT) | Mercy Hospital |   SQV | SQV Report_CoE | Authoring (Default) |
| Tester (UAT) | Mercy Hospital |   SQV | SQV Report_CoE | Authoring (Default) |
| Tester (UAT) | Mercy Hospital |   SQV | SQV Report_GSG |      Under Revision |
```

I actually only need 1 entry for each report i.e. SQV Report_GSG with Status 'Under Revision', and SQV Report_CoE with Status 'Authoring Default' but I'm not able to manupilate the data accordingly.

I have already tried filtering for the MAX(id) but apparently there is an inconsistency in the data which causes the *latest* record to NOT have the highest ID. The inspiration for this action came from the second answer in this question: [SELECT DISTINCT on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966176/select-distinct-on-one-column)

Please find my current "solution" in the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9983a/22

The data you find in the Report_Status table in the example contains data that corresponds with the actual data i.e. id, create_date and update_date.

Please keep in mind that the software I'm using to create this query on does **NOT** support T-SQL or PL/SQL commands.

I hope I was clear, if not, please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: This is typically solved with window functions and `row_number()`

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: @marc_s I did some investigating and discovered that the software I have to use connects to a MySQL database. Hope this helps!