# Select Distinct on one column and eliminate nulls in Select Distinct?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966176/select-distinct-on-one-column) 
I have...

```
    ID  SKU PRODUCT
    =======================
    1   FOO-23  Orange
    2   BAR-23  Orange
    3   FOO-24  Apple
    4   FOO-25  Orange
    5   FOO-25  null
    6   FOO-25  null
```

expected result:

```
1   FOO-23  Orange
3   FOO-24  Apple
5   FOO-25  null
6   FOO-25  null
```

This query isn't getting me there. How can I `SELECT DISTINCT` on just one column and eliminate `null` in `SELECT DISTINCT`?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT ID, SKU, Product,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber
         FROM   MyTable
         WHERE  SKU LIKE 'FOO%') AS a
WHERE   a.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Your desired output and the explanation are conflicting with each other. You state you want to eliminate NULL but you have FOO-25 in the output. I would say all you need is an OR predicate. Where a.RowNumber = 1 OR a.PRODUCT IS NULL.

Comment: I want Distinct Products and product with null values

Comment: Did you try the shot in the dark I suggested? It still seems like what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using John Cappelletti's sample data here is another approach. All you really needed was to add the OR predicate to your where clause.

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[SKU] varchar(50),[PRODUCT] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'FOO-23','Orange')
,(2,'BAR-23','Orange')
,(3,'FOO-24','Apple')
,(4,'FOO-25','Orange')
,(5,'FOO-25',NULL)
,(6,'FOO-25',NULL)

SELECT  *
FROM
(
    SELECT ID
        , SKU
        , Product
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber
    FROM   @YourTable
    WHERE  SKU LIKE 'FOO%'
) AS a
WHERE  a.RowNumber = 1
    OR a.PRODUCT IS NULL --This was the only part you were missing
```

Comment: I never even considered  adding the OR  +1

Comment: Really Thanks, I don't want rownumber column in result

Comment: Well that isn't all that difficult....don't use select *. You shouldn't be using select * anyway. You should always select ONLY those columns you need.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps one approach is using the `WITH TIES` in concert with a conditional `PARTITION`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[SKU] varchar(50),[PRODUCT] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'FOO-23','Orange')
,(2,'BAR-23','Orange')
,(3,'FOO-24','Apple')
,(4,'FOO-25','Orange')
,(5,'FOO-25',NULL)
,(6,'FOO-25',NULL)

Select top 1 with ties * 
 From @YourTable
 Where SKU Like 'FOO%'
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By IsNull(Product,NewID()) Order By ID)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  SKU     PRODUCT
6   FOO-25  NULL
5   FOO-25  NULL
3   FOO-24  Apple
1   FOO-23  Orange
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed your row_number to dense rank:

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[SKU] varchar(50),[PRODUCT] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'FOO-23','Orange')
,(2,'BAR-23','Orange')
,(3,'FOO-24','Apple')
,(4,'FOO-25','Orange')
,(5,'FOO-25',NULL)
,(6,'FOO-25',NULL)

SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT ID, SKU, Product,
                Dense_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY Product) AS RowNumber
         FROM   @YourTable
         WHERE  left(SKU,3) = 'FOO') AS a
WHERE   a.RowNumber = 1
```

Results:

```
ID  SKU Product RowNumber
1   FOO-23  Orange  1
3   FOO-24  Apple   1
5   FOO-25  NULL    1
6   FOO-25  NULL    1
```

Comment: DENSE_RANK basically allows ties and gives them the same weight and keeps a numerical order (1,1,2,3). RANK would also work and works like the olympics (1,1,3)