# Repeated Array will not show using php

Tags: php

I have an array, I want to show only unique "referal_user_id" array. In the code have four array and there are repeated "referal_user_id" i want when one time "referal_user_id" called then not repeated again. Like i want this array as second array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 23
            [user_id] => 21
            [referal_user_id] => 16
            [membership_name] => 4
            [points] => 100
            [used_code] => CEMJ916
            [earned_date] => 2018-06-11 06:34:00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 24
            [user_id] => 22
            [referal_user_id] => 16
            [membership_name] => 4
            [points] => 400
            [used_code] => CEMJ916
            [earned_date] => 2018-05-31 06:42:07
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 25
            [user_id] => 16
            [referal_user_id] => 1
            [membership_name] => 2
            [points] => 200
            [used_code] => CEMJ916
            [earned_date] => 2018-06-06 08:36:46
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 27
            [user_id] => 15
            [referal_user_id] => 1
            [membership_name] => 1
            [points] => 100
            [used_code] => 64FPY1
            [earned_date] => 2018-06-11 06:46:03
        )

)
```

How can i filter unique array 
[image]

This array show like

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 23
            [user_id] => 21
            [referal_user_id] => 16
            [membership_name] => 4
            [points] => 100
            [used_code] => CEMJ916
            [earned_date] => 2018-06-11 06:34:00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 25
            [user_id] => 16
            [referal_user_id] => 1
            [membership_name] => 2
            [points] => 200
            [used_code] => CEMJ916
            [earned_date] => 2018-06-06 08:36:46
        )

)
```

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_pmpro_earn_points");
                                 
                                    
                                    echo '<pre>';
                                    print_r($query);
                                    echo '</pre>';

Comment: You can do it directly in the query with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/966215/133203). You just have to adapt it to your database engine.

Comment: this is my table http://prntscr.com/jtnoob

Comment: can you please correct my code

Comment: `SELECT id,user_id,referal_user_id,... FROM wp_promo_earn_points GROUP BY referal_user_id` should do the trick, by using `GROUP BY` you will not get duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the classic `foreach` to group the array into a multidimensional array. Use `array_values` to convert the multidimensional array to simple array.

```
$result = array();
foreach( $arr as $val ) {
    if ( !isset( $result[$val->referal_user_id] ) ) $result[$val->referal_user_id] = $val;
}

$result = array_values( $result );

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 23
            [user_id] => 21
            [referal_user_id] => 16
            [membership_name] => 4
            [points] => 100
            [used_code] => CEMJ916
            [earned_date] => 2018-06-11 06:34:00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 25
            [user_id] => 16
            [referal_user_id] => 1
            [membership_name] => 2
            [points] => 200
            [used_code] => CEMJ916
            [earned_date] => 2018-06-06 08:36:46
        )

)
```

Comment: @HusainAhmed Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use in_array function to find the duplicate so in that function will skip duplicate and you will get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

just create a blank array and store the referal_user_id in it if that id dosen't exist in array you skip else print.

e.g.

```
$unique_array = array();
$unique_referal_ids = array();
foreach($array as $value)
{
  if(!in_array($value->referal_user_id, $unique_referal_ids))
  {
     array_push($unique_array, $value);
     array_push($unique_referal_ids, $value->referal_user_id);  
  }
}

print_r($unique_array);
```

and you'll get your desired result.