# SQL Server: GROUP BY with one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I tried to set a left join, but when I did the `group by` with one column and selected multiple columns I got an SQL error.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    b.ClientCode,
    b.LastName, b.FirstName,
    b."Id" AS IdClient,
    c.CaseDate,
    b.Gender,
    b.BirthDate
FROM
    dbo.Clients b
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.ClientCases c ON c.ClientCode = b.ClientCode
WHERE
    b.ClientCode LIKE '%1%'
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY, '01/06/2017', c.CaseDate) >= 0
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY, '05/06/2017', c.CaseDate) <= 0
GROUP BY
    b.ClientCode
ORDER BY
    b.ClientCode
```

When I write the query like this:

```
SELECT
    b.ClientCode,
    b.LastName, b.FirstName,
    b."Id" AS IdClient,
    c.CaseDate,
    b.Gender,
    b.BirthDate
FROM
    dbo.Clients b
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.ClientCases c ON c.ClientCode = b.ClientCode
WHERE
    b.ClientCode LIKE '%1%'
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY, '01/06/2017', c.CaseDate) >= 0
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY, '05/06/2017', c.CaseDate) <= 0
GROUP BY
    b.ClientCode, b.LastName, b.FirstName, b."Id",
    b.Gender, b.BirthDate, c.CaseDate
ORDER BY
    b.ClientCode
```

It's working - but it returns duplicate `ClientCode`...

What can I do?

Comment: use DISTINCT in the second query, maybe!

Comment: "i got sql error." - always, ALWAYS provide details of the error. Without it your question could get downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: You're trying to group by a single column without an aggregate, what would you expect SQL Server to do with that logic? What's the goal here, to get `DISTINCT` rows? If so, @DhruvJoshi suggestion is pretty clear.

Comment: The second query can't possibly return true duplicates because you are grouping by all columns.  There must be different names/genders/dates for each of the repeated clientcodes you are seeing.  Add a snippet of the current output to your question and the output you want to get.

Comment: @AaronDietz i'm betting the OP's definition of duplicate is more than 1 row for each `ClientCode`. Which, as you stated, isn't a true duplicate.

Comment: I think you need to have a better understanding of what `GROUP BY` really is, instead of testing different grouping sets

Comment: Duplicate of:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966176/select-distinct-on-one-column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put MAX (or MIN or other aggregate function) for your other columns, because of the GROUP BY.  Otherwise it doesn't know the value you want.

```
SELECT b.ClientCode
    ,MAX(b.LastName)
    ,MAX(b.FirstName)
    ,MAX(b."Id") AS IdClient
    ,MAX(c.CaseDate)
    ,MAX(b.Gender)
    ,MAX(b.BirthDate)
FROM dbo.Clients b
LEFT JOIN dbo.ClientCases c ON c.ClientCode = b.ClientCode
WHERE b.ClientCode LIKE '%1%'
    AND DATEDIFF(day, '01/06/2017', c.CaseDate) >= 0
    AND DATEDIFF(day, '05/06/2017', c.CaseDate) <= 0
GROUP BY b.ClientCode
ORDER BY b.ClientCode
```

I suspect the error you are getting is:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'blah blah' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to why this may solve the problem.

Comment: working on it :) formatting messing me up and I hit save too fast