# Is there a way to get the latest entry that is less or equal to the current time with HQL?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to get the most recent data that isn't  going to be applied until future dates.

For now i'm using the following HQL:

```
int x = goods.getId()
String hql = "FROM PriceTags as atcl WHERE atcl.goods_id = '"+x+"' AND atcl.updatedDate <= CURTIME() ORDER BY updatedDate DESC";
return (PriceTags) entityManager.createQuery(hql).setMaxResults(1).getSingleResult();
```

this will return all the pricetags with an updatedDate that is less or equal to the current time and order it descendingly. After that i just use the first entry it returns.
Is it possible to make a HQL that gets all most updated pricetags for all goods?

For an example the table PriceTags will contain :

```
Id   goods_id   price   updatedDate  
1    101        100     2019-07-30  
2    101        150     2019-07-31  
3    102        120     2019-07-28  
4    102        90      2019-06-29  
5    102        130     2020-01-01
```

Lets say current day is 2019-08-01
i would like to get row 2 and 3, since they're the most recent entry up until current day. row 5 wont be relevant until january next year thus wont be returned.

Comment: Can you include some sample input/output data?

Comment: updated my question with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a WINDOW function for that, see [select distinct on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966176/select-distinct-on-one-column). This can be done with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA):

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "PriceTags")
public static class PriceTag {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private int goodsId;
    private int price;
    private Date updatedDate;
}

...

FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((PriceTag tag) -> {

    Long rowNumber = aggregateBy(ROW_NUMBER())
            .OVER(PARTITION(BY(tag.getGoodsId()))
                     .ORDER(BY(tag.getUpdatedDate()).DESC()))
                     .AS();

    SELECT(tag);
    FROM(tag);
    WHERE(lessEqual(tag.getUpdatedDate(), CURRENT_DATE()) && rowNumber == 1);

});

return query.createQuery(em, PriceTag.class).getResultList();
```

this is the resulting SQL

```
SELECT t0.* 
FROM PriceTags t0 

WHERE ((t0.updated_date <= CURRENT_DATE   ) AND
( ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY  t0.goods_id   ORDER BY  t0.updated_date  DESC   ) = 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I only intent to portray a way instead of giving the proper query.

I assume that goodsId, priceTag and updatedDate are 3 columns in table PriceTag.

```
select distinct(p.goodsId), p.priceTag, p.updatedDate from PriceTag p order by p.updatedDate desc
```