# SQL Distinct on One Column with NO ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a problem where I need to select three columns from a table in Access to populate another table but it needs to be distinct on one column ONLY.  I tried the GROUP BY as follows

```
SELECT [Cust Reference], CustType, County
FROM CustInfo
WHERE [Cust Reference] LIKE "%20%" 
  AND [Cust Reference] LIKE "P1%" 
  AND CustType NOT LIKE "%expired%" 
  AND CustType <> ""
GROUP [Cust Reference], CustType, County;
```

But when I use above with a SELECT INTO and check for duplicates there are some.

I have looking at this post - [SELECT DISTINCT on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966176/select-distinct-on-one-column)

But the `CustInfo` table has no ID column and it is not really possible to do a `LIKE` as the post above describes. I have tried the following and it gives me what I think is the correct output and count on one column

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.[Cust Reference]
FROM CustInfo AS t1
WHERE t1.[Cust Reference] LIKE "%20%" 
  AND t1.[Cust Reference] LIKE "C1%" 
  AND t1.CustType NOT LIKE "%expired%" 
  AND t1.CustType <> ""
```

But when I try to broaden this to include three columns as follows it does not work. I copied the `CustInfo` into `CustInfo_Temp` to work the join.  What needs to be corrected in this query to extract the three columns with DISTINCT ONLY on [Cust Reference}?

```
SELECT t2.[Cust Reference], CustType, County
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT t1.[Cust Reference]
     FROM CustInfo AS t1
     WHERE t1.[Cust Reference] LIKE "%20%" 
       AND t1.[Cust Reference] LIKE "P1%" 
       AND t1.CustType NOT LIKE "%expired%" 
       AND t1.CustType <> "") AS t2
JOIN CustInfo_Temp ON t1.[Cust Reference] = t2.[Cust Reference]
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really want, but aggregation will guarantee one row per `[Cust Reference]`:

```
SELECT [Cust Reference], MAX(CustType), MAX(County)
FROM CustInfo
WHERE [Cust Reference] LIKE "%20%" AND
      [Cust Reference] LIKE "P1%" AND
      CustType NOT LIKE "%expired%" AND
      CustType <> ""
GROUP [Cust Reference];
```

Comment: thanks.  I should have gave some demo data but your query seems to work.  I ran a query in new data to check for duplicates and there were none